# Logging accuracy when using tf.estimator.Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I'm following this tutorial - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn - to build a CNN using TensorFlow Estimators with the MNIST data.

I would like to visualize training accuracy and loss at each step, but I'm not sure how to do that with `tf.train.LoggingTensorHook`.